# Android LinearLayout after FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I want to place 4 LinearLayouts after FrameLayout. So on the first screen i see  FrameLayout then when i scroll down i see the rest of LinearLayouts.
I tried to place it in one big LinearLayout but it shows FrameLayout only or LinearLayout.

Can anyone help me?

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/details_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />


      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/details_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_above="@+id/sample_textview"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <xxx.textviews.RegularTextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/clean_button_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/big_text_size" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are using match_parent as the height for your FrameLayout. Your FrameLayout will fill the entire height available in your parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that one big `LinearLayout` in  a`scrollView`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Put here as many layout you want to add -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```